# Is it better practice to write up-to-date or compatible code?

Tags: java, netbeans, backwards-compatibility

I am a hobbyist java programmer using NetBeans IDE. A problem I face with programming in Java is choosing the correct target JRE version. I understand that most of my friends have at least java 6, but few have a totally up-to-date version with which I compile. I know how to compile for a particular target run-time environment on NetBeans; the problem is that by using an earlier target release of Java, the compiler expects code written in that version.

For a specific example, I occasionally use a Java 8 lambda instead of a `new Runnable(){}`, however the compiler (or at least NetBeans) doesn't accept this 'modern' code. Another example is the use of the diamond operator, or the use of multiple-exception catch statement, neither of which are supported by Java 6. The language evolves and the compiler evolves, but older versions of Java cannot handle the change. To distribute my code, I am forced to use what some might consider outdated code.

My question is: Is it considered good practice or common practice to write Java for an outdated target version to provide compatibility? Is there some form of 'translator' or cross-compiler for Java code?

Comment: It's common. "Good" is highly subjective.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. The only reason to use old versions of Java is if you have legacy problems or corporate limitations. Working as a hobbyst you dont have those limitations, your problems with Netbeans are due configurations issues that you could solve.

Comment: When possible ask the users to upgrade to the target version of your code (say Java 8 for example). If they can't/won't and you need to support them you can either compile to, say, Java 6 or have two versions of your tool, one for Java 6 and one for Java 8. Also Netbeans has support for lambdas since 7.4 I believe.

Comment: Raul Guiu, my friends are lazy and don't upgrade their java. Of course my Java is up to date. I would like to share my stuff, is all.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Is it considered good practice or common practice to write Java for an outdated target version to provide compatibility?

It is common practice.

Whether it is "good practice" or not, is highly context dependent.  There is a pragmatic trade-off between supporting older applications whose developers don't want (or can't) upgrade, and holding back the development of your application by not making use of new (and presumably beneficial) features.

There is no universal "best" answer.

> Is there some form of 'translator' or cross-compiler for Java code?

Effectively, no.  For old versions of Java there were "retro-weavers" which allowed you to run "newer" Java on "older" platforms.  However, this approach seems to have died out by Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it really depends on the standards set by the company/office that you are working for.

From my experience, most of time big companies tries to stay with matured and well established development platforms, they might not give the cutting edge features of the new language, but the companies want the base platforms to be stable and secure first. And if the codebase is large and the project has been in development for a long time, they normally don't bother jumping into the new platform, since  that means they might have to invest more resources to rewriting/refactoring a lot of code, which is not always economically lucrative.

I love using those features that you mentioned in my personal projects, but in my office works we are still using JDK6.

As for the second question, I think there are no workable things at this moment that can do the "translation" that you mentioned.

Comment: It's a pity that the java compiler isn't flexible enough to do the translations. Perhaps a compile-time warning about how 'your special syntax will not be optimised' would be better. I am sure it is not this simple though.

Comment: @bimmo - A pity ... but entirely understandable.  What value is there to Sun / Oracle to make it easy for people to run new software on out-of-date JVMs?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this isn't a big problem in the industry. Java is used mostly on the server, not so much on the desktop. And to setup a server with the required Java version is not a big deal. For desktop applications I also seen the approach to ship the JRE with the application. It is a little bit ugly to ship a small application (let's say 5 MB) with a 60 MB JRE, but in the "enterprise environment" it doesn't matter and is a practical way to provide the correct JRE. However, I don't like this approach since it leaves open questions, like how to ship security updates to the JRE.

And by the way: Is Java 6 still supported? To use an old JRE is pretty big security issue.

Comment: don't worry, I don't infect ASCII art Snake (the game) with too many viruses!

Comment: Haha, I am sure you don't do that ;) But security issues are mostly related to the JRE itself. Security always comes into play when you use an internet connection, a socket, a database connection, an applet... and a lot of apps do that. Of course the app itself is not a virus. But a lot of malware targets the JRE today because it is so widely used.